# What does the "secret characters" extra in Lego Indiana Jones do?

Tags: lego-indiana-jones

Title pretty much says it.  Have been unable to find a definitive answer on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, it allows you to unlock a group of secret playable characters.

For example:  Dancing Girl 2; Thieving Hoodlum 1,2; Santa; Grave Robber 1,2; etc.

None of these has any exciting qualities to them, but they are playable.

I do not believe it has any bearing on any of the other unlockables in the game (*e.g.* Han Solo).

There is an excellent guide to all the characters, as well as unlocking the extra characters in the game [here](http://brickraiders.net/LegoIndy1/characters.html).